# Multiple objects waiting for the same API response

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching

I have an API code, which loads a data necessary for my application.
It's as simple as:

```
- (void) getDataForKey:(NSString*) key onSuccess:(id (^)())completionBlock
```

I cache data returned from server, so next calls of that functions should not do network request, until there is some data missing for given key, then I need to load it again from server side.

Everything was okey as long as I had one request per screen, but right now I have a case where I need to do that for every cell on one screen.
Problem is my caching doesn't work because before the response comes in from the first one, 5-6 more are created at the same time.

What could be a solution here to not create multiple network request and make other calls waiting for the first one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to make a RequestManager class. Use dictionary to cache the requesting request.

1. If the next request is the same type as first one, don't make a new request but return the first one. If you choose this solution, you need to manager a completionBlock list then you will be able to send result to all requesters.
2. If the next request is the same type as first one, waiting in another thread until the first one done. Then make a new request, you API will read cache automatically. Your must make sure your codes are thread-safe.

Or you can use operation queues to do this. Some documents:

[Apple: Operation Queues](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html)

[Soheil Azarpour: How To Use NSOperations and NSOperationQueues](http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues)

Comment: I'm using AFNetworking - do you know if they have anything ready to use for that maybe ?

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski If you are using AFNetworking, have a look at AFHTTPRequestOperationManager. If you create request via AFHTTPRequestOperationManager, request will be add into [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager].operationQueue automatically. By the way, this operationQueue is a NSOperationQueue, you can setup it as you like.

Answer (score 0):

May be there will be so many time consuming solutions for this. I have a trick. Create a BOOL in AppDelegate, its default is FALSE. When you receive first response, then set it TRUE. So when you go to other screen and before making request just check value of your BOOL variable in if condition. If its TRUE means response received so go for it otherwise in else don't do anything.

Comment: Sorry but that's not gonna solve my problem. I want to do something even if there is another request made, but I want to wait for the first to be finished, and return same response to others